# Shortening Bluetooth Range

Tags: android, ios, mobile, bluetooth, range

Is there a way to possibly shorten the distance that two Bluetooth devices can connect in?

To my knowledge, the shortest maximum range is about 30 ft or 10 m. I am developing an android (and later an iOS) app to function with a Bluetooth-capable device (being developed). The product being developed requires certain features to be accessed remotely, but security/safety concerns require that the range not be too extensive. Originally the intention was to have the android app function similar to a TV remote (using IR), but the addition of IR capabilities to the product is an additional (significant) cost, and the device already has Bluetooth capabilities. Is there a way to shorten the range of connectivity to, say, 10 ft? Would this be a feature implemented statically in the hardware, or could I allow the user to set the max connectivity range of the product? (some customers may require more or less security)

I may be able to utilize different connectivity options (Bluetooth, IR, NFC, etc.) but it seemed that Bluetooth would fit the needs of the product best. However, I am open to new ideas.

Comment: cut radio power, or work inside a faraday cage. bluetooth itself doesn't care abou range. if the signal's intelligible, it'll be used.

Comment: How would I cut radio power?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple factors that can affect the Bluetooth range such as:-

- Receiver Sensitivity
- Transmit Power
- PHY used (relevant to BLE only)

I highly recommend the link below as it provides a rough estimate of the range when tweaking the different parameters:-

https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-technology/range/?utm_source=li&utm_medium=social&utm_term=social&utm_content=li-btrange-boost&utm_campaign=range

I hope this helps.